# Select rows from a Pandas DataFrame with exactly the same column values in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, select, rows

Say I have the first pandas DataFrame below:

```
    A      B      ID
0  22.0    male   12
1  38.0  female   34
2  26.0  female   44
3  35.0  female   04
4  35.0    male   78
```

The second pandas DataFrame is:

```
    C   D   ID
0  xx  xx   12
2  xx  xx   44
4  xx  xx   78
```

I want the output be like:

```
    A      B      ID
0  22.0    male   12
2  26.0  female   44
4  35.0    male   78
```

which I only want to select rows from the first DataFrame that has the same ID appeared in the second DataFrame.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
>>> df1[df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])]
      A       B  ID
0  22.0    male  12
2  26.0  female  44
4  35.0    male  78
```

Or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html): (prefer `isin`)

```
>>> df1.merge(df2['ID'])
      A       B  ID
0  22.0    male  12
1  26.0  female  44
2  35.0    male  78
```

Comment: this is based on a single column, not the entire row?